# Is it better to not use Footers within ListView?

Tags: android

What is the advantage of adding/removing and positioning footers within a listview?  would it not be better to display in an area below the ListView?  There are errors that can occur adding/removing footers dynamically.  Moreover when adding it appear (correct me if I am wrong), that the adapter needs to be reset each time the footer is added.

Here is the method I end up using for adding a footer view to a listview, which shows the add/remove stuff.

```
  private void addFooterView(ListView listView, View footerView)
{
    if ((listView != null) && (footerView != null))
    {
        listView.removeFooterView(footerView);
        listView.addFooterView(footerView);
        if (listView.getAdapter() != null)
        {

           listView.setAdapter(mInTheatersMostPopularAdapter);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm confused with this. How do you "position" a footer? It's a footer. It goes at the end of something or it's not a footer.

Comment: It turned out that the whole (empty) list was being repositioned within the layout.  You are correct the footer is always at one position at the bottom of the ListView.

Comment: I have adjusted the question, however, I still find the add/remove sequence to be error prone, and have a few production issues with this as well.  Resetting adapter seems like a cumbersome way to simply add a footer.  I mean if its so dependent on the Adapter, perhaps the adapter is where the footer should be added in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

If a list view already has an adapter, it will throw an exception (illegal state I think) if you try to add a header or footer view ('fixed' views). This is because if the list has a fixed view when you set the adapter, it will wrap your adapter in a HeaderViewListAdapter.

If you want to change a footer in a list view dynamically you need to null out the current adapter add the fixed views then reset your adapter. If you don't have a reference to your adapter, you can get it from the listview, but check to see if it is a HeaderViewListAdapter.
If it is, call getWrappedAdapter on it and keep that as the local variable while you setAdapter(null), addFooterView(footer), setAdapter(oldAdapterHere) in that order.

You can simulate headers and footers by manipulating the data that powers the adapter and having it handle different view types.
Header and footer views aren't recycled as you scroll them on and off the screen, so there are performance considerations - they always take up their full memory, but you're not repopulating, laying out, inflating etc them each time.

Comment: It will not throw an exception for adding a footer view, but it will for adding a header view.  However the footer view will not be shown if the adapter has already been set.

Comment: What about references to header/footer. What about removeFooter(v)? Do you recommend removing the footer? And is there way to get a reference from the listView of the footer or do you need to keep a reference to it if you want to update and or change it?

Comment: Removing fixed views is fine. getView will return fixed views if you give it the position (getCount will include the wrapped adapter's count and any fixed views), it keeps a reference and doesn't reinflate etc them. You can keep references to them as long as you don't retain it longer than you need the list.